# Dynamic directives from within a resource property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a repeater for a resource that contains an attribute with angular directives inside, mixed with text. What I'm trying to accomplish is to show form inputs dynamically depending on the object's property.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="action in actions">
    {{action.form_layout}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In this case `action.form_layout` could contain some text with directives inside that would need to be compiled too.

```
Open the <door></door> with this <key></key>
// <door> and <key> are directives that would return different inputs
// so this should be compiled to Open the <input type="text" name="door"></input> with this <input type="text" name="key"></input>
```

How can I accomplish this? Right now the property value is being printed in the template as plain text.

Thanks

Comment: provide demo with sample data and what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dH5Ln/
Here the `door` and `key` are separated as individual directives. With the help of the `compile` function, we are parsing the template and displaying the compiled template.